# smbclient - Download latest file

Tags: ubuntu, bash, smbclient

Trying to script a file download in Ubuntu from an SMB network server (windows-esque).

I have a folder tree as follows:

- file1.tar.gz
- file2.tar.gz
- file3.tar.gz

These files have different modified dates.

I want to download the **latest** file using smbclient, `get` requires a file name which I won't know what the latest file name is (it won't necessarily be in numeric order).

How do I get the last created file using smbclient? Is there a specific mask in `mget` to do this?

I also hopefully want to do this without any interaction from the user (part of a shell script).

Answer (score 0):

Mount share to some directory then use `ls -1t` to list files sorted according to modification time.

```
ls -1t /mnt/file*.tar.gz | head -n 1
```

Comment: I should say, I don't really want to have to mount it just to download a single file...

Comment: mount/ls/cp/umount will be a bit faster than several smbclient invocations because internally smbclient will do the same low level operations.